# C++ Recursion error message after running code in C++ 17

Tags: c++, recursion

why is keep stopping if I run after running this code somthing wrong happand in windows 7 error message just pop-up

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

void g(int n) {
     if(n == 1) {
        std::cout << " V0id " << std::endl;
        return;
     }
     g(n - 1);
     std::cout << n << " - 1 " << std::endl; 
     g(n - 2);
     std::cout << n << " - 2 " << std::endl;
}

int main(void) {
    g(10);

    return 0;
}
```

`g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -o run.exe main.cpp`

Comment: Are you sure your recursion stops? Add check if `n == 0`

Comment: as written the code does not compile. You cannot `return 0;` in a fucntion declared to return nothing

Comment: Well, if you try to debug your program using 2 instead of 10 as the starting value, you should be able to find the problem very easily as only a few steps is need before the problem occurs. And since you write the output, it is even easier.

Comment: @fas I don't think this condition will help. because value passed becomes a negative number and execution goes to infinite loop. Better add **n < 0**

Answer (score 0):

> windows 7 error message just pop-up

This is because your code is going in infinite loop and application crashed because of "stack overflow".

> if(n == 1)

if not matching when execution goes into

> g(n - 2);

this turns out to be a negative number passed to function and execution goes in infinite loop.
To test this, add

```
cout << "Top" << n << endl;
```

in void g(int n) in the beginning.
You need to change the terminating condition to **n < 1**or something as per you requirement. below is the sample code.

```
void g(int n) {
    cout << "Top" << n << endl;
    if (n < 1) {
        std::cout << " V0id " << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    g(n - 1);
    std::cout << n << " - 1 " << std::endl;
    g(n - 2);
    std::cout << n << " - 2 " << std::endl;
}
```

Hope this will help you. 
If you are not sure about the execution flow, Try debugger or add logs.